# DKIM Script via Powershell

Tags: powershell, dkim

Can anyone assist this is a basic script but doing my head in to get it working.  This is what I have so far.

```
$domain = Get-DkimSigningConfig | Where-Object {$_.enabled -eq $false}
ForEach-Object { 
    $domain = New-DkimSigningConfig -Enabled $true -Identity $domain.Identity
}
```

and i was also working on it from a .csv

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\this is me\domains.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $domain = Get-DkimSigningConfig -Identity $_.Identity
    New-DkimSigningConfig -Enabled $true -Identity $doman.Identity 
}
```

where the .csv has

```
Identity
domainone.com
domainstwo.com
```

Thanks

AL

Answer (score 0):

As there is already a DKIMConfiguration for the Domains you need to use the Set-CmdLet. This should work:

```
$domain = Get-DkimSigningConfig | Where-Object {$_.enabled -eq $false}
$domain | ForEach-Object {
    Set-DkimSigningConfig -Enabled $true -Identity $domain.Identity
}
```